# java.io.IOException: Job status not available about hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I use hive with `select * from table_name;`, it works.

When I use `select t.a from table_name t OR select * from table_name where ...`, the following error happens :

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1414949555870_118360, Tracking URL = N/A
Kill Command = /usr/local/hadoop-2.5.1/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1414949555870_118360
java.io.IOException: Job status not available 
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:322)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getJobState(Job.java:347)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$NetworkedJob.getJobState(JobClient.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure.isJobPreparing(HadoopShimsSecure.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.HadoopJobExecHelper.progress(HadoopJobExecHelper.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.HadoopJobExecHelper.progress(HadoopJobExecHelper.java:541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:431)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:136)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1485)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1091)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:931)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:921)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:684)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:623)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Ended Job = job_1414949555870_118360 with exception java.io.IOException(Job status not available )
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask`
```

So, what's wrong about hive？

DEBUG info as follow, maybe useful!! Please help me!!!

```
15/04/14 16:53:48 DEBUG ipc.Client: getting client out of cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@60cb201b
15/04/14 16:53:48 DEBUG mapred.ClientServiceDelegate: Failed to contact AM/History for job job_1414949555870_118441 retrying..
java.net.UnknownHostException: Invalid host name: local host is: (unknown); destination host is: "slave109":43759; java.net.UnknownHostException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/UnknownHost
```

Comment: Make sure hive server is running and did you tried it running again?

Comment: Throgh it' running, It doesn't work.

Comment: Just now I tried `select t.a from table_name as t` and it worked! See **as** in the query? Can you try that?

Comment: I try it, but still happened again. I think that hadoop is not connected with hive, Or authority problem？

Comment: It is possible, try running it from hadoop user account. But when I look into the error closely, it tells me that somebody is killing the hive job.

Comment: I try running ./hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console, occur this info, I update! Please check it.

Comment: try after starting history server in hadoop...

Comment: Ok, it's done. Missing the hostname of Hadoop in /etc/hosts, now it's Okay!!!